# How to find fields with calculating other fields?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to find a female who has visits to two or more restaurants.

Here are the tables.

Cust:

```
Name  | Gender
--------------
sarah | female
Tim   | Male
```

Visits:

```
Name  | Restaurant
------------------
sarah | Crab City
Tim   | Domino's
sarah | Crab City
sarah | Krusty City
Tim   | Domino's
sarah | Crab City
Tim   | Domino's
```

Everything that I have tried didnt work...
I am using Access to do the quires.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please edit the question with your attempted query(ies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Temp_Table.name AS NameOfPerson 
FROM   (SELECT cust.name, 
               Count(DISTINCT restaurant) AS UniqueRest 
        FROM   visits, 
               cust 
        WHERE  cust.name = visits.name 
               AND cust.gender = 'female' 
        GROUP  BY cust.name) AS Temp_Table 
WHERE  UniqueRest >= 2
```

this will give you the name of females who visited two or more Restaurants.

Comment: Your query is not giving any output

Comment: Thanks it worked, you just had a little error in your syntax. it should be `UniqueRest >= 2` not `UniqueRest => 2`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something as shown below. The gist of it is to join on a subquery where you use group by/having to only return the >2 visit customers

```
select name from Cust
      INNER JOIN 
      (    
        SELECT
          Name,
          Restaurant,     
          COUNT(DISTINCT Restaurant) AS UniqueRest
        FROM
          Visits
        GROUP BY Name
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Restaurant) > 2 
      ) visitingcusts ON cust.Name = visitingcusts.Name AND Cust.gender='female'
```

Comment: when I try to run this, it says JOIN expression not supported. Im using MS Access

Comment: I edited above so that the having clause did not use the column name as this is apparently not supported in access...please try this now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select c.name, count(*) as no_visited
from cust c inner join visits v on
c.name=v.name 
where
c.gender='female'
group by c.name
having count(*)>1;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc2a3/4)